# cycript access elements in JavaUtilArrays_ArrayList

Tags: cycript

I am running cycript on iOS and calling internal API in an App.
I have a variable of type JavaUtilArrays_ArrayList returned from a call

```
cy# l

"[<FieldDescriptor: 0x170a74fc0>, <FieldDescriptor: 0x170a75a00>, <_FieldDescriptor: 0x170a76200>, <FieldDescriptor: 0x170a76240>, <FieldDescriptor: 0x170a76280>]"
```

I would like to iterate over this list to access the elements (preferably with #element)

In general I would iterate like so

```
for (x of [1,2,3]) {x+x}
```

However, trying

```
for (e of l){e}
```

or

```
for(e in l ){l[e]}
```

results in throw new Error("*** _assert(static_cast(static_cast(value)) == value):../Execute.cpp(347):CYCastJSValue")

furthermore, accessing an individual element

```
l[0]
```

Return nothings

I am very new to cycript. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

JavaUtilArrays_ArrayList was just another random objective-c object.
I used class dump to find its definition and appropriate method to access the elements.
I then called the method using objective c syntax [l getvaluefunc:]